# Sweetalert still submit the form after clicking Cancel button

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, submit, sweetalert

I have a Laravel 5.8 project with using [sweetalert.js](https://sweetalert.js.org/).

And I have a form like this:

```
<form id="myForm" action="{{ route('acceptWallet') }}" method="POST">
   @csrf
   <input type="checkbox" id="btn-submit" name="wallet_checked" onchange="this.form.submit();">
</form>
```

As you can see I have used `onchange="this.form.submit();"` to submit the form without using submit button and it works fine.

Then by using this script, I tried showing SweetAlert confirmation message box, containing **Yes** and **No** as buttons:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn-submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let form = $(this).parents('form');
    swal(
        {
        title: "Attention!",
        text: "Are you sure you want to make this transaction",
        type: "warning",
        allowEscapeKey: false,
        allowOutsideClick: false,
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes",
        cancelButtonText: "No",
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }).then((isConfirm) => {
        if (isConfirm) {
            document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Now it works fine but the only problem is that, when I click on **No** button which is *CancelButton*, it still submit the form and call the Action.

So the question is, how can I reject the `submit()` when user press on **No** button?

Comment: Not entirely the answer to your question, but why not just submit the form *after* they click Yes, rather than trying to cancel the submit if they click No?

Comment: @David I just grabbed this code over net and customized it. If you have a better solution, please share with me, I would really appreciate that.

Comment: Remove this `onchange=this.form.submit()` bit and put that inside `if(isConfirm)` (in fact, it looks like you already do submit it in there, so you can just remove the onchange event)

Comment: @David Good idea, but didn't solve the main problem!

Comment: If the only call to `form.submit()` is inside `if(isConfirm)`, then there's no way it's submitting the form if isConfirm is false.

Comment: @David I tried it but after clicking **No**, it still calls the Action and submit the form somehow.

Comment: I think, you need to check like this `if (isConfirm) { form.submit(); } else { throw : null }`

Comment: @sta When I add `throw : null` to `else` condition of `if(isConfirm)`, it does not show SweetAlert popup message box at all. But I tried `console.log("NO");` instead and nothing appears when I click on **No** button.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btn-submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let form = $(this).parents('form');
    swal(
        {
        title: "Attention!",
        text: "Are you sure you want to make this transaction",
        type: "warning",
        allowEscapeKey: false,
        allowOutsideClick: false,
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes",
        cancelButtonText: "No",
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }).then((isConfirm) => {
        if (isConfirm === true) {
            document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If you use sweetalert2, you should change 'if (isConfirm === true) { ... }' to 'if (isConfirm.value) { ... }'

Comment: Now the button **Yes** does not work when I click it

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btn-submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let form = $(this).parents('form');
    swal(
        {
        title: "Attention!",
        text: "Are you sure you want to make this transaction",
        type: "warning",
        buttons: {
            cancel: 'No',
            defeat: {
                text: 'Yes',
                value: true
            }
        },
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }).then((isConfirm) => {
        if (isConfirm === true) {
            document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to set flag on the form you want to trigger with SweetAlert :

```
<form id="myForm" action="{{ route('acceptWallet') }}" method="POST" data-flag="0">
    @csrf
    <input type="checkbox" id="btn-submit" name="wallet_checked">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then you trigger it with JS :

```
const form = $('#myForm');
form.submit(function(e) {
    if (form.attr('data-flag') == 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Attention!',
            text: 'Are you sure want to make this transaction',
            icon: 'warning',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
            cancelButtonText: 'No',
            showCancelButton: true
        }).then((res) => {
            if(res.isConfirmed) {
                form.attr('data-flag', '1');
                form.submit();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

It will prevent from submitting the form if you click **No**

Answer (score 0):

Do this.

Copy this Code

```
     <form class="sldier-form" action="{{ route('sliders.destroy', $slider->id) }}"  method="post">
      @csrf
      @method('DELETE')

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm "  onclick="sliderDelete()">delete</button>
      </form>
```

// jquery script

```
    <script>
    function sliderDelete() {

        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            customClass: {
                confirmButton: 'btn btn-success',
                cancelButton: 'btn btn-danger'
            },
            buttonsStyling: false,
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
        }).then((result) => {
            
            if (result.value == true) {
                
                $('.sldier-form').submit();
                Swal.fire(
                    'Deleted!',
                    'Your file has been deleted.',
                    'success'

                )
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```